# Floating point value isn't being displayed?

Tags: c++

After finding the **standard deviation** I turn the int into a floating point value, yet I'm not sure if I did it right because it is not being printed out. I'm wondering if the problem is in the `conversion` or in the `cout` itself.

```
float standardDev(int num[], int count, int average)
{
    int i,standardDev, sum =0;
    for(i=0;count-1;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (num[i] - average)<<2;
        standardDev = sqrt((1.0/count)*sum);
    }
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    float x = (float)standardDev; //int into floating point
    cout << "The standard deviation is " ;
    std::cout<< x;
    cout << ".";
    return x;
}
```

Currently nothing is being displayed from this function. After trying to display standardDev before turning it into a float, it seems that the main problem is in the math I am trying to do.

Comment: Is anything being printed out?

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Actually, if you tried to extract a minimal example, you would probably find the error (which is rather obvious) yourself.

Comment: `float x = (float)standardDev;` is sort of useless, because by that time the information is already lost.

Comment: What is the reason of leftshift 2 (`<<2`) and are you aware that it is performed after addition?

Comment: How about letting standardDeviation be a float in the first place? Note also you can chain your cout. cout << "..." << standardDeviation << ".\n";

Comment: Nothing is being displayed from this function. <<2 is basically supposed to be the shorter version of pow.

Comment: So what does happen? Does the program hang in an infinite loop? Does it crash with a segmentation fault? Does this code throw an exception that you're catching elsewhere? Does the code somehow return from this function and continue in the surrounding code? etc. Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger to see where it gets stuck / doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: Your for loop either never executes or executes as an infinite loop. You should practice making better use of the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

> After finding the **standard deviation** (...)

I'm afraid that the posted code doesn't do that, considering how the loop is written:

```
for(i=0;count-1;i++)
{ //    ^^^^^^^   This should be a condition like:  i < count
  //    As written, the loop is either skipped (if count == 1, count-1 results in 0,
  //    which is interpreted as false) or endless (count != 1 -> count-1 is true) 

    sum = sum + (num[i] - average)<<2;
    //                            ^^^ Nope. We'll see later.

    standardDev = sqrt((1.0/count)*sum); // That's not how it is calculated and repeating
                                         // it at every iteration is pointless     
}
```

Note that an endless loop without side effects has undefined behavior, so that the compilers are allowed to ignore it.

On top of that, `standardDev` (and `average`) is an `int`, which is later casted to a `float` to be printed, while the result of `std::sqrt` has already a floating point type.

> << 2 is basically supposed to be the shorter version of pow.

There are two problems, here. Given an integer `x`, a bitwise left shift by two bits will effectively **multiply it by 4** (assuming that it doesn't overflow), while you need to *square* the value, in your formula.

Also, due to operator precedence, **the sum is performed before the bitshift**.

Consider using a function, instead, something like

```
double square(double x)
{
    return x * x;   
}
```

Which would lead to the following

```
double standard_deviation(int num[], int count, double average)
{ //                                            ^^^^^^  
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    { //           ^^^^^^^^^
        sum += square(num[i] - average);
    }
    return std::sqrt(sum / (count - 1));
}
```

The next steps of improvements may be to use a standard container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and some of the functions defined in [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: Note: *<< 2 is basically supposed to be the shorter version of pow.* this is true for the number 2, but nowhere else unless you change the base.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is in the for loop. You never specify `i <= count - 1` Otherwise, it will print something, but not the right result. Here is your code.     Now I recommend the following suggestions: turn the num array to floats, and average to float. Then compute it. But unless your nums need to be int and average is int, then you might have to do some type conversion. Here is my recommended code with not much change to your code.

```
     // your code with correction             
     float standardDev(int num[], int count, int average)
        {
            int i,standardDev, sum =0;
            for(i=0;i<=count-1;i++)
            {
                sum = sum + (num[i] - average)<<2;
                standardDev = sqrt((1.0/count)*sum);
            }
            std::cout << std::fixed;
            float x = (float)standardDev; //int into floating point
            cout << "The standard deviation is " ;
            std::cout<< x;
            cout << ".";
            return x;
        }
      // my code below 

      float standardDev(float num[], int count, float average){
            int i = 0;
            float sum, standardDev = 0;
            for(i = 0; i <= count-1; i++){ 
                sum += ((num[i] - average)*(num[i] - average));
                standardDev = sqrt((1.0/count)*sum);
            }
            //standardDev = sqrt((1.0/((float) count))*sum);
            std::cout << std::fixed;
            cout << "The standard deviation is ";
            std::cout<<standardDev;
            cout<< ".";
            return standardDev; 
        }
```

Hope I could help.